# Find doble integral $\int\int_{D}f(x,y)dA$ with the region $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^{2}}:-2\leqslant y\leqslant 3; y^{2}+1\leqslant x\leqslant y+5\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the region $D$ defined as

$$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^{2}}:-2\leqslant y\leqslant 3;\ \ y^{2}-1\leqslant x\leqslant y+5\}$$

And I need to find the double integral

$$\int\int_{D}f(x,y)dA$$

over the $D$ region viewed as region of Type I.

$f(x,y)=1$

**Solution:**

I made this plot:

[image: Plot for the given D region]

So the new region is defined as follows (shaded area):

$$R_{I}\left\{\begin{matrix}
0\leqslant x \leqslant y-5\\ 
-2\leqslant x \leqslant \sqrt{x+1}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is that correct?

Comment: The parabola is $y^2 = x$, not $y^2 = x+1$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff it's typo. I've updated the question.

Comment: There is still at least one typo. The definitions of $D$ in the title and in the body of the question are not the same.